# Reactive Spring Security throws 500 and console stacktrace instead of 401

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-security, spring-webflux

I'm using Reactive Security with JWT. This build works, although when invalid credentials are provided it returns json:

```json
{
    "timestamp": "2021-03-24T12:44:44.540+00:00",
    "path": "/auth/login",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "requestId": "cfa7b741-1"
}
```

and prints stacktrace in the console:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Invalid Credentials
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractUserDetailsReactiveAuthenticationManager.lambda$authenticate$1(AbstractUserDetailsReactiveAuthenticationManager.java:99) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
```

Here is the login controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthAPI {
    private final JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;
    private final ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity> login(@RequestBody Mono<AuthRequest> authRequest) {
        return authRequest
                .flatMap(login -> authenticationManager
                        .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(login.getUsername(), login.getPassword()))
                        .map(tokenProvider::createToken)
                )
                .map(jwt -> {
                            HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
                            httpHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + jwt);
                            var tokenBody = Map.of("token", jwt);
                            return new ResponseEntity<>(tokenBody, httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
                        }
                );
    }
}
```

Security Config:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http,
                                                JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider,
                                                ReactiveAuthenticationManager reactiveAuthenticationManager) {

        return http
                .csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)
                .httpBasic(ServerHttpSecurity.HttpBasicSpec::disable)
                .authenticationManager(reactiveAuthenticationManager)
                .securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance())
                .authorizeExchange(it -> it
                        .pathMatchers("/me").authenticated()
                        .pathMatchers("/users/{user}/**").access(this::currentUserMatchesPath)
                        .anyExchange().permitAll()
                )
                .addFilterAt(new JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter(tokenProvider), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.HTTP_BASIC)
                .build();
    }

    private Mono<AuthorizationDecision> currentUserMatchesPath(Mono<Authentication> authentication,
                                                               AuthorizationContext context) {

        return authentication
                .map(a -> context.getVariables().get("user").equals(a.getName()))
                .map(AuthorizationDecision::new);

    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService(UserRepository users) {

        return username -> users.findByUsername(username)
                .map(u -> User
                        .withUsername(u.getUsername()).password(u.getPasswordHash())
                        .authorities(u.getRoles().toArray(new String[0]))
                        .accountExpired(!u.getIsActive())
                        .credentialsExpired(!u.getIsActive())
                        .disabled(!u.getIsActive())
                        .accountLocked(!u.getIsActive())
                        .build()
                );
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveAuthenticationManager reactiveAuthenticationManager(ReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService,
                                                                       PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        var authenticationManager = new UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager(userDetailsService);
        authenticationManager.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return authenticationManager;
    }
}
```

JWT filter:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter implements WebFilter {

    public static final String HEADER_PREFIX = "Bearer ";

    private final JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        String token = resolveToken(exchange.getRequest());
        if (StringUtils.hasText(token) && this.tokenProvider.validateToken(token)) {
            Authentication authentication = this.tokenProvider.getAuthentication(token);
            return chain.filter(exchange)
                    .contextWrite(ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.withAuthentication(authentication));
        }
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }

    private String resolveToken(ServerHttpRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith(HEADER_PREFIX)) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

I would like to receive correct error code and write my own message, but I can't find a way to configure it.

I tried to add

```
.exceptionHandling()
.authenticationEntryPoint()
.accessDeniedHandler()
```

with exception throwers but it doesn't work.

Thank You in advance!

Comment: why do you have a custom JWT filter when spring already has a jwt filter implemented that you can customize? also you have chosen to write a custom login, and a custom jwt filter so you have essentially opted out of the standard spring security configuration with all its benefits. Which means you need to handle your own errors. If the login fails, you need to handle the return and build your own custom response that you return to the client.

Comment: you are calling `authenticate` and my guess is that the `reactiveAuthenticationManager` returns an error that you dont handle since you are directly calling `.map(tokenProvider::createToken)` just blatantly assuming that the login went fine, and you create a token.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I am no Spring Security expert and was following a tutorial as the documentation was very short and didn't include Webflux with JWT. Also, for some reason, the Spring Security was securing every path behind login, so going to `/` or `/register` wasn't possible, therefore I looked up for custom solution.

Comment: @Toerktumlare Yes, that's why I wrote this question - I needed to handle the error. Although I found a solution that I will post below, Your point is good aswell, as it gave me an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was to either create new authentication manager class extending the one built in as follows:

```java
public class CustomReactiveAuthManager extends UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager {

    public CustomReactiveAuthManager(ReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        super(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Authentication> authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
        return super
                .authenticate(authentication)
                ;
    }
}
```

and use it here in Security Config `var authenticationManager = new CustomReactiveAuthManager(userDetailsService);`

or as @Toerktumlare said, handle the error before providing token in authAPI:

```
                        .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(login.getUsername(), login.getPassword()))
                        .onErrorMap(BadCredentialsException.class, err ->
                                CustomError.authError())
                        .map(tokenProvider::createToken)
```